# difference between uglify and obfuscate? Is one more safe?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, obfuscation, uglifyjs, deobfuscation

Recently I was asked to obfuscate my javascript in order to hide a client's api key. I'm using grunt.

Will [grunt-contrib-uglify](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify) obfuscate my js?

What's the difference between uglify and obfuscate? Is one much more safe than the other?

Comment: I think you'll find both approaches leave the API key exposed, albeit slightly more difficult to discern.

Comment: Uglify minifies, but it does not closure compile and replace variable names, nor does it obfuscate. Also, obfuscation does not improve security.

Comment: I would say that in general obfuscation does improve security at least a little, in the sense that fewer people have the skills to attack the software, or that people would need to spend more time attacking the software. I would agree that there are some particular cases, such as searching for the presence of a certain string, where obfuscation may make no difference. And I wouldn't claim that obfuscation can't be reversed with effort. But if, for example, your aim is to make it harder for people to understand or modify an algorithm, then I think obfuscation does "improve security".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Uglify is a code minification tool. It parses the JS, building a token tree out of the code, which can then be used to either compress/minify the code or 'beautify' it, making it readable for debugging, etc.
Uglify will NOT obfuscate your code.

On the other hand, using an obfuscation tool such as [Stephen Mathieson's Obfuscator](https://github.com/stephenmathieson/node-obfuscator) can concatenate multiple project files into one, bundling requires and packaging. In this case it also Uglifies the entire job at the end, resulting in an obfuscated, minified JS file. It's not 100% secure, there are ways to de-obfuscate JS code, but it makes it much more difficult to decipher than flat text.

HOWEVER, I would recommend keeping a client's API key out of browser-side code whenever possible. Even if it is obfuscated, it can still be found

Comment: just want to point out that as far as I can tell Stephen Mathieson's Obfuscator actually uses UglifyJS as its method of obfuscating code.

Comment: @antfx Thanks for the heads up, I was under the assumption that there was more to it and that Uglify was just a layer as part of it

Comment: I have been playing around js-obfuscator for the last few days, seems to do a good job of obfuscating rather than just ugliflying https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-obfuscator